# Downloading a file via ftp using php

Tags: php, ftp, download

I'm using ftp_put() to download a file from another server. Everything (connection etc.) working but it wont download.

```
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_file); 
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $name, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
```

above is my code and its giving error "Can't change directory to"...
when i out `ftp_put` without 'ftp_chdir' it didn't work so i used `ftp_chdir`. but still not working. `$destination_file` equal to a path and `$name` equal to a file. Please give me an idea what a i doing wrong?
p.s even $upload is returning true. But i can't find the file anywhere.

Comment: http://php.net/ftp_put vs http://php.net/ftp_get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ftp_get` not `ftp_put`

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

[ftp_get from PHP manual](http://php.net/ftp_get)

Comment: guess a bit misunderstanding thanks . but now i get this error. `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and `Error opening` . :| do u knw why??

Comment: seems like another clumsy miss. But now  get this error `ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Can't open http://example.com/folderx/foldery/test.zip: No such file or directory` :(

Comment: @guitarlass Could you please add the complete code you use for connection and downloading to your question so that I can debug it?

Comment: I'll post it in a reply because there is not enough space here. Sorry for late reply. hope you can solve this quickly.

Comment: What do I put in the variable $ftp_server?
The PHP documentation is always very incomplete, its hardly usefull.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code,
`$source_file="http://example.com/ex/ex2/".$file_name;`    and `$destination_file` is equal to a path.

```
     $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // check connection
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
          echo "FTP connection has failed!";
          echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name";
          exit;
      } else {
          echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
      }

    // upload the file
    //ftp_chdir($conn_id, $destination_file); 
    $upload = ftp_get($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) {
          echo "FTP upload has failed!";
      } else {
          echo "Downloaded $source_file";
      }

    // close the FTP stream
    ftp_close($conn_id);*/
```

Comment: what is the value of $ftp_server ?

Comment: and btw add the code to your question not is a separate answer so that everyone can view it

Comment: `$ftp_server` is equal to something like "example.xy.zo" . that's the host name i put in my file upload/download client.

Comment: then your `$source_file` should be something like `"/ex/ex2/".$file_name;`. It's the absolute path without the host.